# How do I write to a folder I created manually (using file explorer on Windows) in my app?

Tags: java, android

Here is what I want/try to do:

- I connected an Android phone to a Windows computer using a USB cable. I can see the phone Internal Shared Storage on the Window's machine File Explore. I go to that Internal Shared Storage and create a folder that I call say "myFolder"...

[image]

- My goal is then to be able to write a file to this director from my Android app. I know how to write 'a' file with Android, what I don't know is how to access from the app that folder that I just created and write a file in it.

My knowledge of Android dev is very limited (just started a few days ago). Even with the code below I can't managed to get the file created for instance in the DOWNLOAD directory? Or PICTURES? and yet, it seems like the process is going through without an exception being raised. So I really don't know where is the file created??? But more importantly what I am looking for is to write files into 'myFolder', so I am sure that if someone can show me how to do that, then I can figure out the rest. Many thx.

```
        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();

        int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
        //String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        //System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>> Path: " + path);

        File file = new File(root, "test.txt");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut, "UTF-8");
        String content = "this is a test";
        myOutWriter.write(content);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
```

What I want to achieve is something like that:

```
File file = new File("myFolder", "test.txt");
```

Comment: To the person who wants to close this question or downvoted please explain your reasons. I think this kind of behavior is just wrong. You said it's not about programming while my question is just about programming. You just didn't even read the content of my question!!!

Comment: Maybe you're getting a permission issue in your code. Because, to my understanding, this line `String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();` should go **after** the permission check.

Comment: `I can't managed to get the file created for instance in the DOWNLOAD directory?`.How can you ask? You SEE that it is next to the Download directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myFolder");

File file = new File(dir, "test.txt");
```